# Fallo con JQuery Cookie

Tags: jquery

Buenos dias. Estoy tratando de instalar la libreria de JQuery "JQuery Cookies". Lo he configurado tal y como me muestra las instrucciones, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me da un error con firebug:

> ```
> TypeError: $.cookie is not a function.
> ```

En el index cargo en primer lugar el jquery, a continuacion el plugin de las cookies, y a partir de ahi, el codigo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>SB Admin 2 - Bootstrap Admin Theme</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
<link href="vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

En el body tengo una pequeña funcion javascript, que guardara en variables cookies el valor de los inputs:

```
 $(document).ready(function(ev){

    $('.container').on('click','#btnIniSesion', function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        $.cookie('usuario', $('#Mail').val());
        $.cookie('clave', $('#Clave').val());


   });
});
```

No se en que puedo estar fallando.

Comment: estas seguro que en esa direccion estan los archivos jquery y jquery-cookie?

Comment: Abre las herramientas de desarrollador (pulsando F12), ve a la pestaña de la consola de JavaScript, mira el error que te está dando (posiblemente un 404) y copialo aquí para que lo veamos

Comment: ¿Qué versión de jquery.cookie.js estas usando?

Answer (score -2):

No sé si has leído la [documentación del autor](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) que te explica como utilizarlo. El error puede ser debido a que no has puesto el link  `<script src="/ruta/jquery.cookie.js"></script>` en el documento.

Comment: estaba mal su codigo, edite y si esta importando

Comment: La ruta del plugin esta incluido: `<script src="jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>` asi que no puede ser eso